# How do i replace or overwrite imagges stored in cloudinary using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, cloudinary

I want to setup user profile pic but do not want to keep adding new files each time they change the picture is there a way to overwrite or replace an image in the cloudinary database
Here is Models :

```
class CloudinaryField(BaseCloudinaryField):
    def upload_options(self, model_instance):
        return {
            'public_id': UserProfile.user.username,
            'filename': "Hey",
            'unique_filename': False,
            'overwrite': False,
            'resource_type': 'image',
            'tags': ['Profile'],
            'invalidate': True,
            'quality': 'auto:eco',
        }


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Nick_Name = models.CharField(default="Hey", max_length=250)
    Profile_pic = CloudinaryField('Profile_Pic', default="")
```

forms :

```
class UserProfilePage(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['Nick_Name', 'Profile_pic']
        help_texts = {
            'Nick_Name': 'This will act as your display name',
        }

    Profile_pic = CloudinaryFileField(
        options={
            'folder': 'Profile/',
                })
```

And finally the views :

```
def edit(request):
    func = data(request)
    form = UserEdit(initial={'email': request.user.email})
    profile = UserProfilePage(initial={'Nick_Name': request.user.userprofile.Nick_Name,
                                       'Profile_pic': request.user.userprofile.Profile_pic.url})
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserEdit(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
        profile = UserProfilePage(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user.userprofile, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and profile.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            profiles = profile.save()
            return redirect("Profile_Page")
    ctx = {
        'form': form,
        'profile': profile,
        'url': func[0],
        'name': func[1],
        'date': func[2],
    }
    return render(request, "Edit_User.html", ctx)
```

If any more code is required please comment it i will for sure edit it into the question
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see what you are passing in `Profile_pic` for class `UserProfilePage`. But under options you should be passing in the upload params:

```
        'public_id': UserProfile.user.username,
        'overwrite': True,
        'resource_type': 'image',
        'invalidate': True,
```

This should overwrite the asset with that public id and invalidate it at the CDN level. It's covered in the Cloudinary docs here:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_image_and_video_upload#django_forms_and_models

Comment: How do i call the public Id ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'ForwardOneToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'username'
I am getting this error

Comment: If you know the user, you should be able to pass in the public id of that profile pic assuming you stored that in your db somewhere.